# Can you use an outdoor paving stone for indoors?

Tags: tile

I want to tile my kitchen with a tile that continues outside to a patio. I have seen a nice 25 mm thick lime stone tile (outdoor) that would look good, but I'm not sure about using an outdoor tile indoors.

We are going to have underfloor heating (water system) under the tiles. I realise that it might take a bit longer, but that's okay.

Are there any disadvantages or anything that I should be aware of?

Comment: I have a friend who had their concrete floor colored, then had a patio made to match.  That might be an option, but I don't know what the minimum depth of an indoor concrete floor is.  (and it might be less of a DIY type job than tiles or pavers)

Answer (score 1):

I'd be concerned about the weight. 25 mm is pretty heavy, and you'll be putting a fridge on top.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_thermal_conductivities
It's actually a better thermal conductor, so it could be beneficial in that area, but:

You also make any future maintenance that require removing such heavy tiles all the more difficult.

You might need to consult with an engineer to see if the particular structure can bear the added load. If the floor starts to sag due to the heavier load, it can cause cracking in the floor.

Comment: Yea, that's a pretty heavy floor, so I'd worry about structure too. That said, the heating shouldn't be an issue. Many houses use heated concrete floors. They act like giant heat sinks so can actually make for a much more even heat throughout the day which can be a benefit.

Comment: You're right. Sloppy thinking on my behalf. Useful list as a reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_thermal_conductivities